# Error when try to redirect from Child grid in Kendo UI Grid using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ClaimTravelCashSelectByApproverId_Result>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.chkbox)
                .HeaderTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='chkAllClaim'/>")
                .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='clsClaim'/>")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
                .Filterable(false)
                .Width(50);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Name)
                .Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("name"))
                .Width(150)
                .Title("Claim");
            columns.Bound(e => e.Description)
                .Filterable(false)
                    .Width(150);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Amount)
                .Filterable(false)
                    .Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Status)
                    .Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.FullName)
                    .Width(150);
            columns.Bound(e => e.CreatedDate).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(CreatedDate,'dd/MM/yyyy'), '" + ProjectSession.DateFormat + "') #")
                    .Width(100);
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(
        @Html.ViewLink("View Comment", "javascript:", null, null, new { datahref = Url.Action("_ViewClaimComment", "Home", new { Data = "#=ClaimId#" }), @class = "clsView" }).ToHtmlString())
        .Width(50);

        })
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:1000px;" })
        .Filterable(filterable => filterable
        .Extra(false)
         .Operators(operators => operators
            .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                .StartsWith("Starts with")
                .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
            ))
        )
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(6)
                    .Read(read => read.Action("claimApproverList", "Approver"))
        )
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound")))

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ClaimSelectByApproverIdByClaimId_Result>()
            .Name("grid_#=ClaimId#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.ClaimId).Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ClaimTypeId).Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ClaimTypeName).Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.NoOfItems).Width(110);
                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(
                    @Html.ViewLink("View", "RedirectByClaimTypeName", "Approver", new { Data = "#=ClaimId#" , TypId = "#=ClaimTypeId#" }).ToHtmlString())
                    .Width(50);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                //.PageSize(10)
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetClaimInnerGridByClaimId", "Approver", new { ClaimId = "#=ClaimId#" }))
            )
            //.Pageable()
            //.Sortable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
)</script>

/* View comment fro claim*/
$(".clsView").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert($(this).attr("datahref"));
    $("#divCommentsdialog").load($(this).attr("datahref")).dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 450,
        width: 600,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        dialogClass: 'no-close success-dialog',
        title: '@objFieldNameList["Claim"]' + " " + '@objFieldNameList["Comment"]',
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
            $("#divCommentsdialog").empty();
        }
    });
});




$("#chkAllClaim").click(function () {
    $('.clsClaim').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});



/* If all checkbox is checked than top checkbox will be checked.*/
$('.clsClaim').click(function () {
    if ($('.clsClaim:not(:checked)').length > 0) {
        $("#chkAllClaim").prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        $("#chkAllClaim").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Now my issues are:

1. when I checked 'chkAllClaim', Kendo grid seems like to be postback and checkbox unchecked (don't know what exactly happens after my js function)
2. when I am clicking on class 'clsView', it doesn't go to js function (when from browser I am inserting that function then working)
3. In my first grid , I got "#=ClaimId#" , for "View Comment" , In second grid(child grid) I also got "#=ClaimId#" , but when I try to get "#=ClaimTypeId#" , I GOT ERROR : **ReferenceError: ClaimTypeId is not defined** (where the hell problem is ?)

I have take reference from here : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use \\ for the inner grid binding before #

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Uhrs.Domain.Entities.EntityPermission>()
          .Name("grid_#=FundUserRoleId#") // make sure the Name is unuque
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(p => p.MenuID).Visible(false);
              columns.Bound(p => p.MenuName).ClientTemplate("<strong>\\#:MenuName\\#</strong>");
              columns.Bound(p => p.MenuStatus).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' \\#: MenuStatus? checked='checked': checked='' \\# class='chkbx' onclick='checkBoxClick(this,#=FundUserRoleId#)' />");


          })
          .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Save())
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:610px;" })
          .DataSource(dataSource =>
              dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Batch(true)
              .ServerOperation(false)
              .PageSize(20)
              .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(p => p.MenuID);
                        model.Field(p => p.MenuName).Editable(false);

                    })
              .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler").RequestEnd("onRequestEndChildGrid"))
              .Read(read => read.Action("ReadUserPermissions", "Admin", new { linkFundUserId = "#=FundUserRoleId#" }))
              .Create(create => create.Action("CreateUserPermissions", "Admin", new { linkFundUserId = "#=FundUserRoleId#" }))
              .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateUserPermissions", "Admin", new { linkFundUserId = "#=FundUserRoleId#", roleID = "#=Role.RoleId#" }))
          )
          .Pageable()
          .ToClientTemplate()
    )
```

Comment: thank you so much #Shaz , thanks a ton :) :)
please also suggest me for my first(1.) and second(2.) issues , these issues are very wired and strange.
its very simple as go but something very wrong from kendo js or jquery.min js and all refreshed
Please help me asap ,,,, your help will be most appreciated ,,thank you

Comment: look at the third bound cloumn in my grid ..its the solution for your 1,2 issues... # is special symbol in when grid is rendered.  for the 1 issue why jquery is not being called is because jquery do not know which document specific cell check box is called. possbility your grid is rendering after the jquery script written which could not find the element .for best practise always write scripts in layout.chtml in the end ..

Comment: thanks for your valueable time and response ... @Shaz :)